# Open source project question in interview

Tags: interview

I've recently applied for a position as C# developer, and during the interview, the interviewers asked me many times if I contribute to develop one or more open source project.

Since they let me write a lot of code (from basics to TDD,MVVM,MVP), I didn't get the meaning of such a question, especially cause they insisted a lot on the topic and the thing started to bother me.

I wish I could have time enough to develop open source software, but I don't get why a company that sells software pretend that their employees work for free in their spare time.

What's the real reason of this question (apart from checking your code)?

Comment: Maybe they read a blog post which said that best candidates worked on open source software and you turned out to be their first applicant who they asked about open source projects. Don't let it bug you. Open source project doesn't mean love for coding or good coding.

Comment: The counter question would be if the company itself supported Open Source projects with manpower.

Comment: @RossPatterson - Do you work for the hiring company the OP applied at?

Comment: @ftr that's exactly what I thought

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is only one way to be sure what was reason for the question, and that's for the interviewer to answer on here.

I can think of several reasons why it might be asked at interview:

- They have had past problems with employees contributing to open
  source projects which have affected the company.  e.g. doing it in
  work time, or cross contamination of source code.
- They thought that they recognised your name as a contributor on a project from your CV - and that's why they brought you in for interview.
- They have a company ethos of encouraging developers to do open source in their spare time, and were looking for a culture match

Answer (score 6):

Writing for open source projects in your spare time can show a love for coding. I can only guess to their reasoning, but maybe they want a programmer who loves programming rather then someone who only considers it work.

Comment: I believe that it also broadens one's horizons as a programmer considerably. It's priceless experience.

Comment: Even before open source was invented, there were programmers who loved coding and who had extremely broad horizons. Like anything else, open source development is a good sign but not a necessary one and not the only one.

Comment: @Steve314: it could be said that open source wasn't "invented", but it's just a name and defintions to recognize the code-sharing practice that is natural for coders that love coding for itself.

Comment: @Javier: why do you assume that everyone who loves coding must love sharing the (presumably source) code? I can assure you - it's not a universal law. Programmers are infamously introverted - another overgeneralisation, but with some truth in it. Of course introverted != selfish, but it can e.g. mean anxiety about criticism. In any case, while contributing to an open source project involves sharing code, they aren't the same thing. There are other ways to collaborate on coding, such as a group of friends developing a closed-source project.

Comment: Not a universal law, but it's pretty common that if you love some activity, it's natural to share it with your peers.  Even more, I'd bet that most introvert find that kind of sharing the only easy way to socialize.  but what I said wasn't that OS is the only way to share, but that OS simply formalizes (and protects) an already existing phenomenon.  Also, your own comment: collaborating among friends on a closed-source project, is still a way of sharing and satisfies that same love of sharing (if you can find enough friends with the same interest).

Comment: @Steve314 everything surrounding open source mostly to what is and what isn't has been so formalized that you could argue that open source is invented.

Comment: @Javier: Remember the context here - an interviewer who repeatedly asks about open source projects isn't likely to get answers that involve other kinds of collaborative coding or other evidence of the love of coding. Asking once, sure, the interviewee might see the point and volunteer other kinds of evidence. Asking over and over again, the interviewee is likely to conclude that the interviewer is obsessed with OS an won't be interested in anything else. My point is that interviewers should be open to other kinds of evidence of a love of coding - these other things exist.

Comment: @Javier: In any case, I love spicy foods but (despite appearances) that doesn't mean I stuff my face with them 24 hours a day. Choosing to work in programming is a clue that someone loves programming. Choosing to spend non-work time with family and friends, in solitary leisure activities, or just relaxing is a clue that someone is less likely to burn out in a year or two.

Answer (score 2):

Don't get too caught up in the whole open source or working for free concept. They want to see code you've written. If all of your work was done for various companies, you're not going to be able to include this work. This is no different than a portfolio for a writer, musician or other type of creative work.

You can write code during the interview process, but there can be drawbacks because of time contstraint and it's difficult to show how you would design larger/more complicated projects, fix bugs, and refactor code.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons is that some people believe, that if you participated in open source projects, you will write better code. This idea comes from a common opinion that the quality of the code in open source projects is higher, since it usually undergoes a review by both the peer developers and the community of the project. This opinion is disputable, though.

Comment: I wonder how many open source projects never see a second developer?

Comment: Probably as many as of those that never get there code reviewed. Of course, not all open source projects are indicative.